# search columns which contains letter and numbers mysql field

Tags: mysql

I have 2 fields in my table one is called BarcodeStart AND BarcodeEnd what i want to do is search for a Barcode for example G1001 which appears between the BarcodeStart AND BarcodeEnd field. The table i have created is below

| OrderID | BarcodeStart | BarcodeEnd |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | G1000 | G1110 |
| 2 | G2000 | G2010 |

So if i search for G1001 i would like the query to return back Order ID 1 as G1001 is between the BarcodeStart AND BarcodeEnd field. I have tried the query below

```
SELECT OrderID  FROM table WHERE 
    (
        (LOWER(BarcodeEnd) = 'G1001' )
    or 
        (LOWER(BarcodeStart) = 'G1001' )
    or
        (
            LOWER(BarcodeStart) > 'G1001' and 
            LOWER(BarcodeEnd) < 'G1001'
        )
    )
```

by no luck the `BarcodeStart` and `BarcodeEnd` are `varchar(100)`

Comment: Why are you calling `LOWER()` if you're comparing to a string with uppercase `G`?

Comment: Change `>` and `<` to `>=` and `<=`, then you won't need to add the `=` conditions separately.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparisons are backwards. You want `'G1001' > BarcodeStart`. But you can simplify all of this by using the `BETWEEN` operator.

```
SELECT OrderID  
FROM mytable 
WHERE 'G1001' BETWEEN BarcodeStart AND BarcodeEnd
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gADt4MXq4czKWnokMYpb4u/0)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use SUBSTRING_INDEX() function (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substring_index.asp).

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT `OrderId`, 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(`BarcodeStart`, 'G', -1) AS `Start`,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(`BarcodeEnd`, 'G', -1) AS `End`
       FROM `Table1`) as `Table2`
WHERE `Start`<=SUBSTRING_INDEX('G1001', 'G', -1)
  AND `End`>=SUBSTRING_INDEX('G1001', 'G', -1);
```

G10001 is the input value.

I hope it helps